# Blue Image Filter in python

Tags: python

I am trying to write a function that takes a pixel as a parameter and inverts each color in the pixel then return the new color values as a tuple. Help would be much appreciated Here is my current code:

```
IMAGE_URL = "https://codehs.com/uploads/c709d869e62686611c1ac849367b3245"
IMAGE_WIDTH = 280
IMAGE_HEIGHT = 200

image = Image(IMAGE_URL)
image.set_position(70, 70)
image.set_size(IMAGE_WIDTH, IMAGE_HEIGHT)
add(image)

#################################################
# Write your function here. Loop through each pixel
# and set each pixel to have a zero blue value.
#################################################
def remove_blue():
    pass

# Give the image time to load
print("Removing Blue Channel ....")
print("Might take a minute....")
timer.set_timeout(remove_blue, 1000)
```

Comment: What seems to go wrong?

Answer (score -1):

```py
from PIL import Image
# open image
image = Image.open('pic.jpeg')
# show the image (optional)
image.show()
# load the image into memory
image_data = image.load()
# obtain sizes
height,width = image.size
# loop over and change blue value to 0
for loop1 in range(height):
    for loop2 in range(width):
        r,g,b = image_data[loop1,loop2]
        image_data[loop1,loop2] = r,g,0

image.save('changed.jpeg')
```

The corresponding function would be

```
def remove_blue(image):
   
   image = Image.open('pic.jpeg')
   # show the image (optional)
   image.show()
   # load the image into memory
   image_data = image.load()
   # obtain sizes
   height,width = image.size
   # loop over and change blue value to 0
   for loop1 in range(height):
       for loop2 in range(width):
           r,g,b = image_data[loop1,loop2]
           image_data[loop1,loop2] = r,g,0
 # return image
   image.save('changed.jpeg')
```

Comment: Thanks for the help, but I am still having trouble. Where do I place the code?

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last): File VFS.browser.timer.py line 13, in f msg='{0.info}\n{0.__class__.__name__}: {0.args[0]}'.format(exc) TypeError: remove_blue missing 1 positional argument: 'image'

Comment: You need to specify the image file Try `remove_blue(IMAGE_URL)`

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last): File VFS.browser.timer.py line 13, in f msg='{0.info}\n{0.__class__.__name__}: {0.args[0]}'.format(exc) TypeError: remove_blue missing 1 positional argument: 'IMAGE_URL'